# jquery templating plugin - using a normal unnamed array?

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know if it's possible to just use a normal array (e.g. [1,2,3]) with the jQuery templating plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work like you intended. Unless you're talking about an array of objects to iterate over in your template. But because like everything else in JavaScript, Array() returns an object, which means it's a valid parameter, but I don't think anything will output, since jQuery.tmpl probably checks if the given data object is an array.

Comment: Yep, I know about arrays being objects, I was just hoping to find a template tag for just getting the value. in the end I just did this:   $.each( messages, function ( index, value ) {
          messageList.push({ 'message' : value });
        } );